# htacess redirect 410 gone

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I've changed my URLs to friendly URLs and had more two parameters so it can rewrite and make a URL structure.

My old URLs look like this one:

```
  product.php?name=Cal%E7as+de+Sarja+em+Castanho&id=27
```

And changed to:

```
 product.php?cat=homem&scat=cal%E7as+de+sarja&name=Cal%E7as+de+Sarja+em+Castanho&id=27
```

What I want to do is a redirect 410 gone for the old URL (if it´s the best way to solve this problem).

Comment: I have no idea what *"had more two parameters so it can rewrite and make a URL structure"* is supposed to mean; this question would benefit from you running it by a friend or colleague to try and improve the English, if you're able to do so.

Comment: `product.php?cat=homem&scat=cal%E7as+de+sarja&name=Cal%E7as+de+Sarja+em+Castanho&id=27` is not *"friendly"*.

Comment: @MarkAmery  maybe i dont have expressed well....my friendly url are in this example 'homem/calças de sarja/calças de sarja em castanho/27' and with only two parameters i cannot put "homem" and "calças de sarja " in the url. I´ve talked in url structure because i have two main categories ( homem and mulher) and some subcategories ( calças de ganga and calças de sarja...) and each subcategory have different products on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /product\.php\?name=(.+?)&id=(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=410,L]
```

This will redirect your old url to HTTP ERROR 410 .

Comment: It worked. But now appears this message "Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."...Maybe i have to had the path of my 410 error document in the rewrite rule?